# Why ConcurrentModificationException in Vector？

Tags: java, multithreading, vector

Here is my test :

```
public static List<String> list =new Vector<String>();
@Test
public void main(){
    new ThreadOne().start();
    new ThreadTwo().start();
}
public static void printAll(){
    String valueString= null;
    Iterator<String> iterator=list.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        valueString = (String) iterator.next();
        System.out.print(valueString+",");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
public static class ThreadOne extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        int i=10;
        while(i<100000){
            list.add(String.valueOf(i));
            printAll();
            i++;
        }
    }

}
public static class ThreadTwo extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        int i=0;
        while(i<100000){
            list.add(String.valueOf(i));
            printAll();
            i++;

        }
    }

}
```

and I saw the source code in about the iterator in Vector.class:

```
 public synchronized Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}

/**
 * An optimized version of AbstractList.Itr
 */
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    int cursor;       // index of next element to return
    int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
    int expectedModCount = modCount;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        // Racy but within spec, since modifications are checked
        // within or after synchronization in next/previous
        return cursor != elementCount;
    }

    public E next() {
        synchronized (Vector.this) {
            checkForComodification();
            int i = cursor;
            if (i >= elementCount)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            cursor = i + 1;
            return elementData(lastRet = i);
        }
    }
```

I was confuced about it.When the program carried out the iterator.next(),
the vector Object was locked，While the program carried out the list.add(),the vector was locked,too.The variable “expectedModCount” always equals “modCount”. Why the ConcurrentModificationException occured？

Comment: It throws an exception because it's modified *between* calls to `next()`. You would have to synchronize over the entire iteration to make it thread-safe. What's surprising is that I don't see this documented explicitly on the `Vector` class, as it is for [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-).

Comment: @shmosel If you post that as an answer, I shall upvote it.

Comment: you can check more here http://www.journaldev.com/378/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception which gives you more clear idea how to fix this

Comment: @DavidWallace It's not very satisfying. I'm of a mind to post it as a question.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator's next method is what's synchronized. That means it releases the lock after reading each element, then acquires the lock when reading the subsequent one. There is still an opportunity between calls to next for the contents of the vector to change in a way that triggers the ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: whether is when I create Iterator<String> iterator=list.iterator();

Comment: it is when u do iterator.next(), the value doesn't get updated , and thread is not safe , which causes the problem

Comment: Ok,Is that right :when thread one  create Iterator<String> iterator=list.iterator();the expectedCount = modCount.But thread two change modCount. So when thread one carried out iterator .next().The problem occurred????